# Trying to understand vhdl led blinking code

Tags: vhdl

I have a led blinking code for `MachXO2 breakout board` written in VHDL. Actually I am new to VHDL.

I am not able to understand the meaning of these lines:

```
--internal oscillator
   COMPONENT OSCH
      GENERIC(
            NOM_FREQ: string := "53.20");
      PORT( 
            STDBY    : IN  STD_LOGIC;
            OSC      : OUT STD_LOGIC;
            SEDSTDBY : OUT STD_LOGIC);
   END COMPONENT;
BEGIN
   --internal oscillator
   OSCInst0: OSCH
      GENERIC MAP (NOM_FREQ  => "53.20")
      PORT MAP (STDBY => '0', OSC => clk, SEDSTDBY => OPEN);
```

Can you please tell me What these lines are doing?

Answer (score 4):

These lines use an externally defined component, called `OSCH`, that magically provides a clock on the `osc` output as long as the `stdby` input is low.

The `osc` output is then connected to the `clk` signal and the `stdby` input connected to `0` (i.e. the switch-off function is not used.

Comment: you should find a package called OSCH which (if you are lucky its vhd) will show you the lower-level logic associated with that.  I find it helps with VHDL to think of it like wiring chips up and a component is an IC and portmaping is wiring